# how to connect 2 objects in ionic via backand

Tags: angularjs, object, ionic-framework, backand

i need a bit of help to my ionic project. so i want to connect 2 objects in ionic, so that i can display the value of and object that has data from the other object.

```
<ion-list class="list-inset">
  <ion-item class="item-text-wrap" ng-repeat='item in todos| filter:firma'>
  <h2>{{item.company_name}}</h2>
 </ion-item>
 <ion-item class="item-text-wrap" ng-repeat='item in todos2 | filter:{ idcompany:com_id } '>
 <h2>ponedeljek {{item.time_mon_start}}-{{item.time_mon_end}}</h2>
 <h2>torek {{item.time_tue_start}}-{{item.time_tue_end}}</h2>
 <h2>sreda {{item.time_wed_start}}-{{item.time_wed_end}}</h2>
 <h2>četrtek {{item.time_thu_start}}-{{item.time_thu_end}}</h2>
 <h2>petek {{item.time_fri_start}}-{{item.time_fri_end}}</h2>
 <h2>sobota {{item.time_sat_start}}-{{item.time_sat_end}}</h2>
 <h2>nedelja {{item.time_sun_start}}-{{item.time_sun_end}}</h2>
</ion-item>
```

this is what i want to display for the current company that i click on, but it shows all the times not only one that i want.

```
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, TodoService, cas, $state) {
$scope.todos = [];
$scope.todos2 = [];

function getAllTodos() {
  TodoService.getTodos().then(function (result) {
    $scope.todos = result.data.data;
    $scope.firma = $state.params.aid;

  });
}
getAllTodos();

function getalltimes() {
  cas.getcompany().then(function (result) {
 $scope.todos2 = result.data.data;
});

}

getalltimes();
})

.service('TodoService', function ($http, Backand, $state) {
var baseUrl = '/1/objects/';
var objectName = 'companies/';

function getUrl() {
return Backand.getApiUrl() + baseUrl + objectName;
}
function getUrlForId(id) {
return getUrl() + id;

}
getTodos = function () {
return $http.get(getUrl());
};
return {
getTodos: getTodos
}
})

.service('cas', function ($http, Backand, $state) {
var baseUrl = '/1/objects/';
var time = 'companies_timetable/';

function getUrl2() {
return Backand.getApiUrl() + baseUrl + time;
}
getcompany = function () {
return $http.get(getUrl2());
};
 return {
getcompany: getcompany
}
})
```

this is now my app.js file and my connection to the backand service. this is working fine.

[this are the companys from object 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PG9UD.png)

[and this are the times showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOZvq.png)

so when you click on the companys it should show the time for it. but here it shows all times that are in the object. i should show only one for the one company
i was trying to give all objects in one array (todos). but didn't worked rlly well. so please i need some help. if you need some more code or somthing just say it :).

Answer (score 0):

Your second filter is wrong.

Simplest way to fix it is to call a function in $scope.

Change your filter like this:

```
 <ion-item class="item-text-wrap" ng-repeat='item in todos2 | filter: isCurrentFirma '>
```

Then add a function in your controller:

```
$scope.isCurrentFirma = function(item){
  // here check if item is equal to firma

  // code like this:
  return item.idcompany === $scope.firma.com_id
}
```

Comment: somehow it gives me the same result that i got. now i get again all the times not only one that i need.

Comment: i went into the console and there it says that com_id is undefined.

Comment: okay got it that the function is ok but now it wont show any time when i klick on a company